# Unable to finish Actvity using SharedPreferences and apply condition for go another activty

Tags: android

```
public class userdetail extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_detail);
        imageView_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);
        button_selectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        Upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        button_selectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        Upload.setOnClickListener(this);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        city = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.City);
        String[] languages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citylist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, languages);
        city.setAdapter(adapter);
        city.setThreshold(1);
         prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        member_id = prefs.getString("Member_id", "");


        Boolean startSecond1 = prefs.getBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", false);
        // ....................................//
        if (startSecond1) {
            Intent newpage = new Intent(userdetail.this,
                    ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(newpage);
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Name = name.getText().toString();
        City = city.getText().toString();

        if (v.getId() == R.id.uploadButton) {

            if (Name.toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entere Your Name",
                        10000).show();
            } else if (City.toString().length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Your City",
                        10000).show();
            } else {

                if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(userdetail.this)) {

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);

                    // Writing data to SharedPreferences
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("mEmberUsername", Name.toString());
                    editor.putString("mEmberUserCity", City.toString());
                    editor.putBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    new Uploadimage().execute();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please Check ur Internet Connection",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

This code i have write for from Userdetail to Contact Activity while User Activity is coming from Actviation.javaclass .there is some field i have to Enter to go upload data to server new Uploadimage().execute(); using this Asynk task suppose currently now i am coming from activation class to user detail class now i did not fill Information in Userdetail class  and sudden i have put back button or home button then i launch app it userdetail class is not open now its goes to Contactclass while it should on userdetailclass please tell me where am doing wrong and tell me Solution for this .

Answer (score 1):

when activity start you check for this value  `startSecond1 = prefs.getBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", false);`

but after click you change   `"StartSecondActivty1"` to true and it's not call oncreate again that's why your activity was not finish

Comment: hello @Danish Aziz how to apply condition suppose i have Button click then ?

Comment: call it on onresume function
   Boolean startSecond1 = prefs.getBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", false);
        // ....................................//
        if (startSecond1) {
            Intent newpage = new Intent(userdetail.this,
                    ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(newpage);
            finish();
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...

prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        member_id = prefs.getString("Member_id", "");


        Boolean startSecond1 = prefs.getBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", false);
        // ....................................//
        if (startSecond1) {
            Intent newpage = new Intent(userdetail.this,
                    ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(newpage);
            finish();
        }

}
```

Comment: when ever user return on your screen it will sent to another activity if condition is true

Comment: You should edit your first answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @DanishAziz i unaderstand Userdetail to ContactActivty am able to go But Problem Suppose i am On Userdetail and now i have press back button then activity Userdetail becomes finish and it go to Contact activity without taking User detail Information so please tell me Solution for that

Comment: on backpress call this code
 // Writing data to SharedPreferences
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("mEmberUsername", Name.toString());
                    editor.putString("mEmberUserCity", City.toString());
                    editor.putBoolean("StartSecondActivty1", true);
                    editor.commit();

Comment: it will save your data while you are leaving userdetail activity